# All the drag events work fine except drop (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple sortable list and all the drag events are triggered correctly however, for some reason drop() event does not respond. I'm thinking it has something to do with overlapping other events but removed the other events and it still doesn't work??

```
const richestPeople=[
    'Jeff Bezos',
    'Bill Gates',
    'Warren Buffett',
    'Bernard Arnault',
    'Carlos Slim Helu',
    'Amancio Ortega',
    'Larry Ellison',
    'Mark Zuckerberg',
    'Michael Bloomberg',
    'Larry Page'
]

function createListItems() {
    richestPeople.forEach( (person,index)=>{
        const newItem=document.createElement('li');
        newItem.setAttribute('data-index',index);


        newItem.innerHTML=`
        <span class=number>${index+1}</span>
        <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
            <p class="person-name">${person}</p>
            <i class="fas fa-grip-lines icon"></i>
        </div>
        `
        listItems.push(newItem)


        draggable_list.append(newItem)
        console.log(listItems)
    });


    addEventListeners();
}

function addEventListeners() {
    const draggables=document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
    const dragListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-list li');

    console.log(dragListItems)

    draggables.forEach( (draggable)=>{
        draggable.addEventListener('dragstart',dragStart)
    } );
    
    dragListItems.forEach( draggableItem=>{
        draggableItem.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
        draggableItem.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver);
        draggableItem.addEventListener('dragenter',dragEnter);
        draggableItem.addEventListener('dragleave',dragLeave);
    })
}
```

Comment: What is your `dragDrop` call back? I do not see that code in your question.

Comment: function dragDrop() {
   console.log('Event: ', 'drop');
}